# qt5 QGraphicsScene setBackgroundBrush() not always work when called frequently

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I want to write an tool of objective annotation using qt5 MinGw32, which could annotate object in video file and diplay them during playing. So **QGraphicsScene** is inherited to implementation the function.

Something wrong happens when I change the QGraphicsScene's background frequently(e.g. 30 fps): most of time it works as expected while sometimes the background could not move.

Here is my code:

```
void MyGraphicsScene::UpdateFrame(QImage image)
{
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

    //fix the view's size and scene's size
    views().first()->setFixedSize(pixmap.size());
    setSceneRect(0,0, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height());

    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(pixmap));
}

...

//In another thread
void Thread::run()
{
    ...

    myScene.UpdateFrame(newImage);

    ...
}
```

I have search through the qt's document and found no answer.

However, there is something strange:

when wrong thing happens, I find the background continues to change, but it didn't show change on the screen unless I move the app to another screen (I have two screen). However, with the app moved, the QGraphicsScene's background just change once and becomes static afterwards.

I guess the background has been changed but doesn't repainted, so I used **update()**, but it didn't help.

BTW, I couldn't reproduce the occasion, sometiems it happens, somtimes not.

do I need to represented any methods? Or I called the methods in a wrong way? Or is there an alternative approach that would work?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: From the posted code it appears you're using `QPixmap` functionality on a non-GUI thread.  That's not allowed (you should probably get warnings at the console).

Comment: @G.M. Thanks.  I have just used `QImage` to set the backgound rather  than `QPixmap`,  and it also works. However, I couldn't confirm the background will no longer get stuck since I don't know why it happen. BTW, the console show nothing warming.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change QtGui elements from a different thread by calling a method directly.

Use the Qt signal-slot concept. 
Calling update() is not necessary.

```
class MyGraphicsScene{...

....
signals:
void singalFromThread(QImage image);

public:

//CTor
MyGraphicsScene()
{
connect(this, SIGNAL(singalFromThread(QImage)),this,SLOT(UpdateFrame(QImage)));
}

//Call this method from your thread
void updateForwarder(QImage image)
{
//Jump into gui thread
 emit singalFromThread(image);
}

public slots:


void UpdateFrame(QImage image)
{
setBackgroundBrush(....);
}


};
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works and the scene seems no longer to get stuck. Here it is another question: does the slot called in uncertain time ,using signal-slot mechanism intead of calling directly, since I hope to control the fps? e.g. will the slot be called in later time if so many signal waiting in the queue?

Comment: Signals from differrent threads are stored at the end of the Qt Gui main Thread event queue. So no data gets lost. Do not send more than 60 signals per second. A standard display has only 60 fps.